# chrome topsites with new tab override extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to show user's top sites in my new tab extension. I have a few questions about chrome.topsites api:

1. I only get 10 sites every time. Can I get more?
2. I don't get new sites. I get always the same sites even if I go to new sites multiple times. Why is that?

In Firefox I used browser.topsites.get({newtab: true}) and I do get new sites.
Is there something similar to this in chrome? I read the dcoumentation and didn't find answers.
Thank you!

Comment: In Chrome you will only get the 10 sites. To force an update you'll have to add and remove a URL via chrome.history, then call chrome.topSites in the callback.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the only way I can force an update? kinda wanted to avoid using history permission

Comment: Another case when Chrome updates it is when the **default** empty new tab is opened (chrome://newtab).

Comment: @wOxxOm can you give a little bit more info? Can you just put random URL each time you want to get an update?

Comment: I didn't try it myself. Try and if it won't work, open a new question.